# Moving Data between VC's Not Working

Tags: objective-c, viewcontroller

I know I've recently asked a question slightly similar to this one but I'm submitting the project in a few hours and this is my only bug left.

In the first VC:

```
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
SecondViewController *theVCMover = [[SecondViewController alloc] init]; //I imported the .h file

    theVCMover.rawUserInput = textView.text;
    //If I put an NSLog of theVCMover.rawUserInput here, it works and displays the string

    theVCMover.hexOrBinIndex = hexOrBin.selectedSegmentIndex; //same problem here
```

In the second VC:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog (@"Bt-dubs, the moved text is %@", rawUserInput); //is (null) here
    CleanerText.text = rawUserInput; //CleanerText is a TextView
}
```

I can't move the text the user input in the first VC to the second VC. I tried debugging and theVCMover.rawUserInput IS initialised and it DOES receive textView.text and saves it successfully in the first VC but then it gets lost in moving to the second VC and appears as (null) there. I've tried so many different ways over the night, each with its own dead end...but this one's fairly simple so I'd like to use it in my future projects.

P.S. At first I cared too much about the moved string displaying right after the second tab is pressed (Second VC) but now all I care about is to just move that bloody string successfully. Eternal thanks!!

Comment: Can you show your code that performs the transition to the second view controller?

Comment: That's it up there from the start of the SecondViewController instance...is there more code I should write to perform the transition?

Comment: At the moment in the first code block you create an instance of a `SecondViewController`, and assign it to a local variable (`theVCMover`). Where do you perform the segue, or push it onto a navigation controller, or whatever you need to do to make `theVCMover` appear?

Comment: I thought I didn't need to...so how do I push it onto a navigation controller (tab bar over here)?

Comment: Oh, it's a tab bar controller... OK - the issue is probably that you're setting your text in a new instance of SecondViewController, and you should be setting in in the one that the TabBarController has a reference to. I'll post an answer for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to push text to a view controller that already exists in a tab bar, you should not init a new one in that `textViewDidEndEditing` method. You should change the text in the VC the tab bar already has.

```
// Not nice code because it uses magic numbers and fixed locations of view
// controllers in the tab bar
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
  // Assumes the SecondViewController is the second tab on the tab bar controller
  SecondViewController *theVCMover = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1]; 

  theVCMover.rawUserInput = textView.text;
  theVCMover.hexOrBinIndex = hexOrBin.selectedSegmentIndex;
  .....
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: IT WORKED! My day has been made, seriously, much thanks! Ok, just a couple of trivial questions along the way: 

How do I know the name of my tab bar controller? It suggested it anyway but I checked its inspector tabs in storyboard and didn't find it.

Where do I write code that loads every time the tab is pressed and not only the first time it loads?

Thanks a lot again!

Comment: I've updated the code sample as a `UIViewController` automagically maintains a reference to a parent `UITabBarController`. For loading something everytime a tab is pressed, you can either do that in the `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:` methods of the incoming view controller, or set a delegate for your `UITabBarController` and implement the `tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:` method.  Also, if the answer answers your question, feel free to accept it :-)

Comment: Thank you so much though...it seems so simple; I don't know why people use singletons and complicate it all...

Answer (score 0):

Is it a scope problem? You haven't shown the code after your theVCMover.hexOrBinIndex assign. Presumably that's where you display the second VC (like you push it or something). Otherwise when textvewDidEndEditing exits, theVCMover will go out of scope and the changes you had made would be lost when the view is actually loaded. You could NSLog theVCMover and then 'self' in viewDidLoad, these should be the same object. If they are not the view you have loaded is not the one you init'ed

Comment: Yeah, I just realised that...how do I push the one I init'ed into the view I'm opening?

Comment: you could just present a modal VC - which would place the new VC in front of the previous one and when you dismissed the new one you'd go back to the other one (check out presentModalViewController and dismissModalViewController).

Or if you have a UINavigationController hosting your first VC then you'd use pushViewController into the Navigation VC

Hope this isn't too terse to make sense of